# Pandas: flag a value modification through columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','a','b','b','c','c'],'date':[201708,201709,201708,201709,201708,201709],'value':[0,15,20,30,20,0]})

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
     date id  value
0  201708  a      0
1  201709  a     15
2  201708  b     20
3  201709  b     30
4  201708  c     20
5  201709  c      0
```

And I have this derived pivot table:

```
In [26]: base=pd.pivot_table(df,index='id',columns='date',values='value',aggfunc='sum',fill_value=0,margins=False)

In [27]: base
Out[27]:
date  201708  201709
id
a          0      15
b         20      30
c         20       0
```

I need to create another df from this pivot table. In this new dataframe I need to show the values, for each id, that are larger than zero on date=t and evaluated as zero on the prior date(date=t-1). The result that I need is this df:

```
date  201708  201709
id
a          0      15
b          0       0
c          0       0
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is `df`, use `pd.DataFrame.where`

```
df.where(
    df.gt(0) & df.shift(axis=1).eq(0),
    0
)
```

Comment: This is smart ! :-)